# Using Google play services on phonegap build

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, velocity

I am new to Phonegap. I am developing an application where i need to use Google Play Games services.There are many tutorials to use the services while building the application on local machine in eclipse.But as i am using Phonegap build and building the app online,i did not find any information regarding using the services on PG build.Any support would be of great help.

Comment: Maybe this will help get you started: https://github.com/ptgamr/cordova-google-play-game

Comment: Thanks for the link.Looks promising.So i just need to download and include the googpleplaygames.js file in my project and use the functions appropriately??...And also is it that i can test the app for the services even before publishing it or is it only possible after publishing..Thanks.